# How to implement tooltip in HTML 5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, tooltip

[image]

I have drawn  this using HTML 5 canvas. I need to show a tooltip when I click on the user picture.

```
    var kin = new Kinetic("myCanvas");

    kin.setStage(function(){
       var context = kin.getContext();
       kin.beginRegion();

       // draw rectangular region  including photo
       context.beginPath();
       context.rect(X + 50, Y + 50, 62, 72);
       context.closePath();


        kin.addRegionEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";



        });
     }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-image-mouseover/

As far as a 'tooltip' - draw your text in a rectangle, or something suited to your design.

Then on mouseout, clear the region.

Comment: Link in your answer is broken.

Comment: @MohammadUsman - Link as it stood when this answer was posted (6 years ago): https://web.archive.org/web/20111211050528/http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-image-mouseover/